# Filter a list of strings but the filter must appear at a certain place

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a python dataframe with a column populated with strings of the same length like `0302000C0AABGBG` , `0407020B0AAAGAG`, `040702040BGAAAC`

I want to filter to identify all values that contain 'AA' but it must be at position _________AA ____ i.e. do not include `040702040BGAAAC` in results.

How do I achieve that?

Current searches yield `str.contains` but I can't find how to specify the position of the substring.

Comment: `str.endswith`?

Comment: you can implement nested conditions using `np.where( <condition A> & <condition B>, <match response>, <no match response>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append to your regex `\w{4}$` (requiring that four word characters occur at end of line) in `str.contains` call

Comment: Sorry formatting happened at the end. 4 random letters must appear after `AA`

Comment: Then use `AA\w{4}$` as your matcher